# Why this file read got flagged as Cross Site Scripting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss

Corporate run all of our source code through a vulnerability scanning software, and the following line got flagged as Cross Site Scripting:

```
divFooter.InnerHtml = Utilities.Utils.ReadFromTextFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(Folders.Templates, Constants.Files.Templates.FooterEN));
```

Where `Constants.Files.Templates.FooterEN` is a const string and `Folders.Templates` is calculated by: `Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "Templates")`.

Why is reading a template file XSS? They are in the same folder as the html files, so they are not less secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a false positve. The tool probably flags every assignment to `InnerHtml` that comes from `sensitive sinks`, in this case `ReadFromTextFile`.

In your particular case it may not be a real vulnerability, now imagine if the text file was submitted somewhere by the user, it would result in a real `XSS` vulnerability.

The tool analyzes statically the code, so it does not know if the result of `Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "Templates")` is secure or not.